# How to create an array of neighbors out from each element in an numpy 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create an array of neighbors for each element in an array. Is there a way to use vectorisation techniques to speed it up?

I've used a nested for loop to iterate through each element in the array to create.

Initial array

```
self.grid = np.zeros((256,256), np.uint)
```

Array of neighbors out  of the initial array

```
        for i in range(256):
            for j in range(256):

                grid = [[self.grid[i-1][j-1], self.grid[i][j-1], self.getGrid[i+1][j-1]],
                        [self.grid[i-1][j], self.grid[i][j], self.grid[i+1][j]],
                        [self.grid[i-1][j+1], self.grid[i][j+1], self.grid[i+1][j+1]]]
```

(This code doesn't account for edge cases)

Comment: By the way, your code rewrites grid every time it enters the loop. I suspect you wanted to use the method `append` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.roll()` to shift the array and generate an array of the neighbors. This has the added benefit of "rolling" the boundaries (ie the right side of the rightmost element is the leftmost element).

In regards to your example, here is a possible implementation using `np.roll` although I doubt it is the cleanest:

```
left=np.roll(self.grid,1,axis=1)
right=np.roll(self.grid,-1,axis=1)
down=np.roll(self.grid,-1,axis=0)
up=np.roll(self.grid,1,axis=0)
leftbottom=np.roll(left,-1,axis=0)
rightbottom=np.roll(right,-1,axis=0)
lefttop=np.roll(left,1,axis=0)
righttop=np.roll(right,1,axis=0)

neighbors2 = [np.array(i) for i in zip(*(np.ndarray.flatten(i) \
for i in (left, right, down, up, leftbottom, rightbottom, lefttop, righttop)))]
```