# numpy store the neigborhood as new (3rd) dimension into matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, convolution, neighbours

Given a numpy array like:

```
L = 2
np.random.randint([-1,1],size=(L,L), dtype=int)
array([[1, -1],
       [-1, 1]])
```

How can I transform it into an array of similar shape (efficiently)

```
np.random.choice([-1, 1], size=(2,2,4))
array([[[-1, -1,  1,  1],
        [-1, -1,  1, -1]],

       [[-1,  1, -1,  1],
        [ 1, -1,  1,  1]]])
```

But unlike shown here where the 3rd dimension is random to contain the 4 neighbors in it (0-padded on the corners).

I.e.

```
[[1, -1], [-1, 1]]
```

has for the first element a neighborhood of:

- 0, 0, -1,-1,
- for the second 1,0, 0, 1 and so on.

I want to store this neighborhood vector into the 3rd dimension of the matrix.

Is this possible without manually looping the matrix?

### edit

For the example of:

```
[[1, -1], [-1, 1]]
```

[[[0,0,-1-1],
[1,0,0,1]],

...]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56032778/how-to-create-an-array-of-neighbors-out-from-each-element-in-an-numpy-2d-array seems to be partially related

Comment: Based on your input array, `[[1, 0], [0, 1]]`, will you please show a sample output array that you want to get?

Comment: please see the edited question

Comment: Hmm...it's still confusing to me.

Comment: Basically like the convolution operator https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350400158/figure/fig2/AS:1005540972974080@1616751058064/a-Standard-2D-Convolution-With-a-fixed-filer-size-the-standard-convolution-computes-a.png though I want to consider left, upper, right and bottom (4) neighbors (not the diagonal ones) and store them into an array/matrix which has 4 entries (we start with the original 2x2 matrix) but for each of the entries instead store an array/vector with these 4 neighbors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
#sample array
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
print(a)
```

It gives:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
```

Compute the array of neighbors:

```
p = np.pad(a, 1)
out = np.empty((*a.shape, 4), dtype=a.dtype)

out[..., 0] = p[:-2, 1:-1] #up
out[..., 1] = p[2:, 1:-1]  #down
out[..., 2] = p[1:-1, :-2] #left
out[..., 3] = p[1:-1, 2:]  #right
```

Then, for example `out[2, 1]` is `[4, 0, 6, 8]` i.e. the array of neighbors of `a[2, 1]` in the `[up, down, left, right]` order (with 0 padding).